# Find values of parameter $m$ for which $m9^x + 4(m-1)3^x+m>1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I am asked to find all values of $m$ for which:

$$m9^x + 4(m-1)3^x+m>1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

The possible solutions are:

**A.** $(- \infty, 1)$

**B.** $[1, + \infty)$

**C.** $(0, + \infty)$

**D.** $(1, + \infty)$

**E.** $\emptyset$

I got to a point and then I got stuck. This is what I tried:

$$m9^x + 4(m-1)3^x+m>1$$

$$m9^x + 4(m-1)3^x+m - 1 > 0$$

Here I used the substitution:

$$t = 3^x, t > 0$$

And then the expression became:

$$mt^2 + 4(m - 1)t + m - 1 > 0$$

I know that this is true iff:

$(I). m > 0$. This is because we need a convex parabola for the expression to be $>0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$(II). \Delta = b^2-4ac$ must be $<0$. This way the parabola is above the $Ox$ axis in its entirety, therefore always positive.

$$\Delta = 16(m-1)^2-4m(m-1)$$

$$\Delta=4(m-1)[4(m-1)-m]$$

$$\Delta=4(m-1)(3m-1)$$

Solving $\Delta < 0$, I got:

$$m \in \bigg (\dfrac{1}{3}, 1 \bigg )$$

Combining this with the condition from $(I)$ I get:

$$m \in \bigg ( \dfrac{1}{3}, 1 \bigg)$$.

So my conclusion is that for $m \in \bigg (\dfrac{1}{3}, 1 \bigg )$, I have:

$$mt^2 + 4(m - 1)t + m - 1 > 0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$

But these are not the solutions for the initial expression. $m \in \bigg ( \dfrac{1}{3}, 1 \bigg )$ are the solutions for the transformed expression, where $t = 3^x$. So how can I translate these values of $m$ for which the transformed, $t$-based expression is true into an interval of values of $m$ for which the initial, $x$-based expression is true? Obviously, this interval would have to be among the $5$ given possible answers **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** or **E**.

Or, alternatively, if my approach seems inefficient or flat out wrong, I'd appreciate it if you could guide me towards the right approach.

Comment: What do you mean by a "solution"? Do you want to solve for $x$, or for $m$? In other words, are the possible solutions given for $m$ or for $x$?

Comment: Note that answer (C) may have a typo, in the usage of the "]" - It should be ")" instead.

Comment: @NoChance Unless you plan on counting to infinity anytime soon, C definitely has a typo.

Comment: @N.Bar, I thinks it is a type, however, it might have been intentionally written this way.

Comment: @NoChance I have to solve for $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward approach. Rearrange the inequity as

$$m > \frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{3^{2x}}{4\cdot 3^x+1}}$$

The RHS is a sigmoid function with the range $(0,1)$. Thus, the answer (B), $[1,\infty)$, always satisfies the inequity.

Comment: What kind of sigmoid function is that? I am familiar with the sigmoid function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ and I know that it's range is indeed $(0, 1)$, but I can't say that I have ever seen this kind of sigmoid function before.

Comment: @user1502 - the Sigmoid function refers to a family of functions that exhibit the same behavior, i.e. varying like a S-curve smoothly between 0 and 1. The rhs is of such a function. I refer to it for convenience. It is not crucial, though. As you pointed out the important observation is that it is less than 1.

Comment: And how can I know that when I see a certain function, it is from the family of sigmoid functions? For example, again, I am familiar with the sigmoid function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, but if you wouldn't have pointed out, I wouldn't have known that the function you have, $\dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{3^{2x}}{4 \cdot 3^x + 1}}$, is a sigmoid function. How can I recognize them?

Comment: @user1502 - Notice that, for this particular function, $\frac {3^{2x}}{4\cdot3^x+1}$ behaves similarly as $e^x$, that is, like an exponential function, varying from 0 to infinity.

Comment: But shouldn't it behave like $e^{-x}$, since that is what $\dfrac{3^{2x}}{4 \cdot 3^x + 1}$ replaces in the sigmoid function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$. I know that it even if it behaves like $e^x$ and **not** like $e^{-x}$ it still varies from $0$ to $\infty$, but now it is strictly increasing, instead of strictly decreasing, like $e^{-x}$. Does this not matter? Why?

Comment: @user1502 - You're right. It behaves like $e^{-x}$, but with $x\rightarrow -x$. It won't matter; it is just a reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I wrote this answer before my comments above were answered. This answer is based on the assumption that the ranges given for the solution options are for the variable $m$.

for:
$$ f(m,x)= m9^x + 4(m-1)3^x+m \tag0$$

as I understand, we need to find the domain for m which makes $f(m,x)>1$.

Regarding your solution, I assume that it follows a correct path, but the solution of:
$$mt^2\:+4\left(m-1\right)t+m-1=0 
\tag1$$
is (for m not equal zero):

$$t=\:\frac{-2m+2\sqrt{\left(3m^2-7m+4\right)}}{m},\:\:\frac{-2m-2\sqrt{\left(3m^2-7m+4\right)}}{m}$$

Which is different from what you have.

The expression in (1) has real values for $t$ when $m=\frac{4}{3}$ or $m=1$.

You now need to check $f(1,x)$ ,$f(\frac{4}{3},x)$. This is rather lengthy and may not be easy.

**Another approach**, probably simpler, is to remove invalid options as follows:

When m=$0$,

$$f(0,x)= -4(3^x)$$

The above value is always negative, so answer (E) is excluded. If (E) is wrong, then (A) is wrong.

Now you have to choose between (B), (C)  and (D).

Given the way option (C) is written, it encloses infinity, so it is an impossible option. As a result we need to consider (B) or (D).

Considering (B), Test $m=1$, to get:

$$f(1,x)= (9^x)+1$$

When $f(1,x)>1$:

$$(9^x)+1>1$$

That is:

$$(9^x)>0$$

The above is always true.

Since you have to pick only 1 answer, then (B) is correct and there is no need to test (D) since (D) must be wrong if only one answer is correct.

Edits Made: Due to discussion below I made 2 edits regarding the invalidity of (C) and (D).

Comment: You checked for $m=0$ and got $f(0,x) = -4(3^x)$, which indeed is always negative. But doesn't that simply mean that $m$ cannot be $0$, since then the function would be negative, while I have to find the values of $m$ for which the function is always $>1$. How did you reach the conclusion that answer (E) must be excluded? If we found that $m$ cannot be $0$, that doesn't mean that we found that there are values of $m$ for which $f(m, x) > 1$. And why did you also exclude answers (A) and (D) afterwards?

Comment: @user1502 $f(0,x)$ is always negative implies that m is not zero which leads to excluding answer (E). Notice that the value $m=0$ belongs to the interval in both answers (A) and (D). Since m=0 is not possible, (A) and (E) are not possible answers. If you want to solve for $m$ then it is a first degree equation and the the other answer is easier.

Comment: But if we know $m$ is not $0$, it doesn't mean that $m \notin \emptyset$. If we know that $m$ is not $0$, we can still reach the conclusion that $m \in \emptyset$. And besides, $0$ is indeed part of the interval of answer (A), but the interval of answer (D) is $(1, + \infty)$, so it doesn't have $0$ in it.

Comment: You are correct about the point that if $m=0$, answer (D) is not rejected. However, I don't understand your first sentence in the last comment  "But if we know m is not zero...".

Comment: You found that $m$ cannot be $0$. Then, you concluded that answer (E) cannot be correct. I don't understand the logic. If we know that $m$ is not $0$, it doesn't mean that $m$ cannot be in $\emptyset$. If we know that $m \neq 0$, there are still chances to find that $m \in \emptyset$, so we cannot exclude $\emptyset$. But we can exclude $\emptyset$ after finding that $f(1, x) > 1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, since now we know that $m=1$ is a solution, so $m \in \emptyset$ cannot be a solution. If we know that there is a solution, we can exclude $\emptyset$, but not if we know $m \neq 0$.

Comment: 1-"You found that m cannot be 0. Then, you concluded that answer (E) cannot be correct. I don't understand the logic.", well, answer (E) say $m=0$ and since $m$ can't be zero, then (E) is wrong.2-" If we know that m is not 0, it doesn't mean that m cannot be in 0" - I am sorry but I can't figure out what you mean. Could you give me an example? Maybe if you try to plot the curve things will become clearer.  I wish there was an easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: But answer (E) **doesn't** say that $m = 0$. Answer (E) is $\emptyset$, the empty set!

Comment: OK, that means that answer (E) means no such $m$ that makes the equation >1. However, from the above $f(1,x)>1$, this makes answer (E) not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer first, by direct calculation, then a short answer, by deduction.

You have two mistake in your solution.  Fisrt, the expression
$$f_m(t)=mt^2+4(m-1)t + m-1$$
need to be strickly positive for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $t = 3^x$, it need to be true only for $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

$m>0$, so the parabola is positive after the rightmost root. And this rightmost root can't be greater than $0$. The parabola can be $\leq0$ as long as it is for $t\leq 0$.

Second, you made a mistake in the calculation of $\Delta$.
$$\Delta = 4(m-1)(3m-4)$$
$\Delta<0$ for $m\in\left(1,\dfrac43\right)$, those values of $m$ are accepted.

If $m=1$, $f_1(t) = t^2$, it is a parabola with vertex at $(0,0)$. $f_1(t)>0$ if $t>0$, it is an accepted value.

For other values of $m$, the roots of $f_m(t)$ are given by
$$\dfrac{-4(m-1)\pm \sqrt{4(m-1)(3m-4)}}{2m} = \dfrac{4-4m\pm\sqrt{4(m-1)(3m-4)}}{2m}$$
Sine $m>0$, the rightmost root is
$$\dfrac{4-4m+\sqrt{4(m-1)(3m-4)}}{2m}$$
If $m<1$, this expression is positive, so every value of $m<1$ is not part of the solution.

If $m\geq \dfrac43$, we need to show that 
$$\dfrac{4-4m+\sqrt{4(m-1)(3m-4)}}{2m}\leq 0$$
Since $3m-4 < 4m-4$, 
$$\dfrac{4-4m+\sqrt{4(m-1)(3m-4)}}{2m}\leq \dfrac{4-4m+\sqrt{4(m-1)(4m-4)}}{2m}= 0$$
Every value of $m\geq \dfrac43$ is an accepted value

Answer B. $[1,+\infty)$.

---

Short answer

Since it is a multiple choices question, we can find the answer by deduction. A lot of answer have $m = 1$ as boundary, so we'll check if it work.
$$(1)\cdot 9^x+4((1)-1)3^x+ (1) = 9^x+1 >0 \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}$$
$m=1$ is part of the solution. Possible answer B. or C.

Does it work for $m=\dfrac12$?
$$\left(\dfrac12\right)\cdot9^x+4\left(\left(\dfrac12\right)-1\right)3^x+\left(\dfrac12\right)=\dfrac{9^x-4\cdot3^x+1}{2}$$
If we take $x = -1$ then
$$\dfrac{9^{-1}-4\cdot3^{-1}+1}{2}=-\dfrac19 < 1$$
$m=\dfrac12$ is not part of the solution, which rule out answer C.

Thus B. is the answer.

Comment: You said "$m>0$ , so the parabola is positive after the rightmost root. And this rightmost root can't be greater than $0$." Why can't the rightmost root be greater than $0$?

Comment: @user1502 your parabola can't have a positive root.  If it has a positive root, the parabola will be negative between $0$ and this root. E.g. take the parabola $y=(x-1)(x+1)$. The roots are $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=1$. The parabola is negative between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: I understand what you said, but what's the problem if the parabola will be negative between $0$ and the positive root? I mean, the parabola will be negative between the minimum point and the rightmost root anyway, regardless of where it is placed, be it before (or at) $0$ or after $0$. What goes wrong if the parabola is negative between $0$ and a positive root?

Comment: @user1502 In your question, you need to have $$m9^x+4(m-1)3^x+1>1,\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$. With your substitution $t = 3^x$, it became $$mt^2+4(m-1)t+(m-1)>0.\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$ But there is no $x$ in the last inegality. But for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $t = 3^x >0$. So the second inegality need to be true only for $t>0$. Thus the rightmost root of the parabola can't be greater than $0$.